# dh_install can't find file

Tags: debian, dpkg

I'm trying to create a new package, but I'm having issues with configuration file. In the root directory, I have all my source files and configuration files. When I try to build a package, binaries are created (from my source) and copied correctly to where it should. The problem is that I have one '.ini' file that simply doesn't copy to package. dh_install returns "not found" for this file.

This is my struct:

```
/myproject/rbfeeder.ini
/myproject/sources.c, etc...
/myproject/Makefile
/myproject/debian/rules
/myproject/debian/mypackage.install
```

When I run `dpkg-buildpackage -b -us -uc`, I'm getting this error: `/home/pi/rbfeeder_source/rbfeeder_split/debian/rbfeeder.install: 1: /home/pi/rbfeeder_source/rbfeeder_split/debian/rbfeeder.install: rbfeeder.ini: not found`

This is my rules files:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# See debhelper(7) (uncomment to enable)
# output every command that modifies files on the build system.
#DH_VERBOSE = 1

# see EXAMPLES in dpkg-buildflags(1) and read /usr/share/dpkg/*
DPKG_EXPORT_BUILDFLAGS = 1
include /usr/share/dpkg/default.mk

# see FEATURE AREAS in dpkg-buildflags(1)
#export DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS = hardening=+all

# see ENVIRONMENT in dpkg-buildflags(1)
# package maintainers to append CFLAGS
#export DEB_CFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND  = -Wall -pedantic
# package maintainers to append LDFLAGS
#export DEB_LDFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND = -Wl,--as-needed

export DH_VERBOSE=10

# debmake generated override targets
# This is example for Cmake (See http://bugs.debian.org/641051 )
#override_dh_auto_configure:
#   dh_auto_configure -- \
#   -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)

override_dh_installinit:
    dh_systemd_enable -prbfeeder --name=rbfeeder rbfeeder.service
    dh_installinit -prbfeeder --no-start --noscripts
#   dh_systemd_start -prbfeeder --no-restart-on-upgrade

override_dh_install:
    dh_install
    install -d debian/rbfeeder/usr/bin  
    cp -a rbfeeder debian/rbfeeder/usr/bin/rbfeeder
    cp -a dump1090-rb debian/rbfeeder/usr/bin/dump1090-rb

override_dh_systemd_start:
    echo "Not running dh_systemd_start"


override_dh_usrlocal:

# main packaging script based on dh7 syntax
%:
    dh $@ --with=systemd
```

and this is my rbfeeder.install file:

```
rbfeeder.ini etc/
```

Comment: What `debhelper` compatibility level are you using?

Comment: ```Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9)```

Comment: That’s not quite the compatibility level ;-). What does `debian/compat` contain? 9 as well?

Comment: ```Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9)``` and ```debian/compat``` are 9.